# Calling layout on a subset of nodes in a loop does not properly layout the nodes

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have several groups of nodes, and I need each group to be its own circle around a different location.

I have a for loop that adds the nodes to the chart, and at the end gets those nodes, and attempts to circularize them.

However when I run the program, the nodes end up in a grid format.
**How do I get the expected behavior?**

```
    for( group in groups ){
        cy.add([
                { group:'nodes', data: { id: 1, customgroup: group}, position:{x: 0,y: 0} },
                { group:'nodes', data: { id: 2, customgroup: group}, position:{x: 0,y: 0} },
                { group:'nodes', data: { id: 3, customgroup: group}, position:{x: 0,y: 0} },
                { group:'nodes', data: { id: 4, customgroup: group}, position:{x: 0,y: 0} },
                { group:'nodes', data: { id: 5, customgroup: group}, position:{x: 0,y: 0} },
                { group:'edges', data: { source: '1',target: '2', weight:1} },
                { group:'edges', data: { source: '2',target: '3', weight:1} },
                { group:'edges', data: { source: '3',target: '4', weight:1} },
                { group:'edges', data: { source: '4',target: '5', weight:1} },
                { group:'edges', data: { source: '5',target: '1', weight:1} }
               ]);
        cy.elements('[customgroup="'+group+'"]').layout({ name: 'circle', radius:1, startAngle: 13*((Math.PI)/8)});
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of no progress, I stepped away, built a fire in the fireplace, and had a scotch. In the moment I forgot about the problem entirely for the night, the solution hit me.

Cytoscape has the option in initialization to specify the layout of nodes. When I implemented the above, I removed the layout from the init so as to avoid positioning the nodes twice.

The proper way to handle this is to set:

```
layout: {
        name: 'preset',
        padding: 10
      },
```

This allowed my custom code to properly handle the desired behavior, and also prevents a double positioning of the nodes.